# odoo 13 community edition, date constraint with respect to start date, end date, employee and store

Tags: python, date, validation, constraints

I am trying to build a condition where the store has a s_start_date and s_end_date.

The employee working for the store also has a start_date and end_date.

Let's assume:

Case1------------

store_name: store 1
s_start_date = 12/01/2019, s_end_date = 12/30/2019
Employee_name: Emp1
start_date = 12/01/2019, end_date = 12/20/2019 #Required result
start_date = 11/01/2019, end_date = 01/20/2020 #It should throw an error as the dates are out of store contract.

case 2-----------------
The condition here is that only one employee is needed at a single store

store_name: store 1
s_start_date = 12/01/2019, s_end_date = 12/30/2019
Employee_name: Emp1
start_date = 12/01/2019, end_date = 12/20/2019 #Required result

Employee_name: Emp2
start_date = 12/21/2019, end_date = 12/30/2019 #Required result
start_date = 12/05/2019, end_date = 12/17/2019 #Should throw an error saying that employee already exist for the time frame or dates not available

**Please find the attached code for your reference .​**

```
from odoo import models, fields, api
from odoo.exceptions import ValidationError

class wv_location(models.Model):
_name= "wv.location"

   storel_name = fields.Char(string="Store Name")
   s_start_date = fields.Date('Store Start Date', required=True, index=True)
   s_end_date = fields.Date('Store End Date', constrains="_check_date")
   emp_loc_id = fields.One2many('wv.emp.location', 'employee_loc_id', string="Employees")

   @api.constrains('s_start_date','s_end_date')
   def _check_date(self):
      if self.s_start_date > self.s_end_date:
          raise ValidationError('End date must be greater than start date')
```

---

```
class wv_emp_location(models.Model):

_name = "wv.emp.location"

   employee_id = fields.Many2one('hr.employee', 'Employee', ondelete='cascade')
   employee_loc_id = fields.Many2one('wv.location', 'Employee Location', ondelete='cascade')
   start_date = fields.Date('Start Date', tracking=True)
   end_date = fields.Date('End Date', tracking=True)

   @api.constrains('start_date','end_date')
   def _check_date(self):
      if self.start_date > self.end_date:
          raise ValidationError('End date must be greater than start date')
```

---

Please let me know if you need more information on this. I know I can use loops and lists but not sure of how to use for these conditions and not sure of logic.

Thank you

Comment: @Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd.